# react redux best practice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Lets imagine i have an app that has a component to display a blog post, and a component to display an array of comments for that blog post. The post and its comments are retrieved from an API whenever a user views a post.

> When the user navigates from one post to another, should I remove the
>   previous post data and its comments from the store? or should I simply
>   keep them in the store and filter by the post id?

Comment: Its totally a matter of choice and what behaviour you want in your application. Both methods are fine to do. I save them in the store and display then again next visit to the same post, and do the fetch again for new comments but show the old ones until it is fetched.

Comment: As you're using redux so the better way to use them from redux store

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like `state.post` in the store, which represents the *currently shown post*, you should replace its content when another post is shown.

If you want to cache viewed posts for some reason, you'd maintain them in an object and access them via ids as you suggested. This allows you to show a previous post instantaneously, but then other issues come into play: Fetching an updated version of the post from the server, fetching new comments to the same post, etc.

Unless you are really sure you need optimization here, I'd avoid caching the posts.

Comment: Thanks timotgl, that makes sense. As I am new to this I'm struggling to get my head around the whole concept. If I select the 10 most recent posts from the API, and have a posts reducer. The next time I fetch the 10 most recent posts, will that automatically replace the 10 in the store or will it potentially add an additional 10 to the store... OR is it simply a case of how I implement this in the reducer?

Comment: 'is it simply a case of how I implement this in the reducer'. Yep if you append your fetch results to the store you will then have 20 recent posts, if you replace you will stay with the last 10 most recent